# OCaml equivalent to Haskell's @ in pattern matching (a.k.a. as-pattern)

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, ocaml

In Haskell, while pattern matching, I can use `@` to get the entire structure in a pattern. (For easier Googling, this structure is known as an as-pattern.)

For example, `x:xs` decomposes a list into a head and a tail; I can also get the entire list with `xxs@(x:xs)`.

Does OCaml have something like this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `as`:

```
let f = function
| [] -> (* ... *)
| (x::xs) as l ->
  (*
   here:
   - x is the head
   - xs is the tail
   - l is the whole list
  *)
```

Answer (score 13):

Let me extend Etienne's answer a little bit with some examples:

```
let x :: xs as list = [1;2;3];;
val x : int = 1
val xs : int list = [2; 3]
val list : int list = [1; 2; 3]
```

When you write `<pattern> as <name>`, the variable `<name>` is bound to the whole pattern on the left, in other words, the scope of `as` extends as far to the left as possible (speaking more techically  `as` has lower priority than constructors, i.e., the constructors bind tighter). So, in case of the deep pattern matching, you might need to use parentheses to limit the scope, e.g.,

```
let [x;y] as fst :: ([z] as snd) :: xs as list = [[1;2];[3]; [4]];;
val x : int = 1
val y : int = 2
val fst : int list = [1; 2]
val z : int = 3
val snd : int list = [3]
val xs : int list list = [[4]]
val list : int list list = [[1; 2]; [3]; [4]]
```